# "denote XXX shortly by X" or "denote shortly XXX by X"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

I think these two forms are correct:

- We will denote XXX shortly by X.
- We will denote shortly XXX by X.

However, I don't know which one is more natural.

Comment: It's really hard to tell which is more natural when you use XXX and X. I really wish more people would write real sentences instead of using placeholders like that, particularly when asking about which is more natural. Sometimes, verbs and prepositions work better with some objects than others.

Comment: @J.R. I have done it in such a way because this kind of problems appear in mathematics where you abbriviate one long symbol with another shorter one. Let's say that XXX=A_{phi} and X=A.

Comment: We will abbreviate or We will represent *A_{phi}* **as** *A*.

Comment: @StoneyB I would avoid word "represent", because it has some mathematical meaning sometimes. Does the word "denote" fit for such purpous or should I use "abbreviate"? However, it still does not answer my original question.

Comment: I'm not sure *shortly* is the word you want at all.  *Shortly* means something like "very soon", not "in a short way".

Comment: People do not *denote* symbols--symbols *denote* meaning: "We designate X to denote XXX."

Comment: Shortly means ***soon***, and in short form means in short form. ***Let X stand for the short form of XXX***.  In math, things stand for other things, they do not denote them.

Comment: @FallenApart - Until you made your comment, I had no idea you were even thinking within the mathematical realm. For all I know, you could have been an architect trying to say something like, "We will denote doorways shortly by _DRWY_." That's why some additional information would help.

Comment: @J.R. This is due to my misunderstanding of the word "shortly". However, I am sure that I read in some mathematical papers the word "shortly" in this context. Just google "denote shortly" and see for yourself. Eventually, shortly after your comments I decided to remove the word "shortly" :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to say that X is a short form of XXX, then neither of your sentences expresses this clearly.  "Denote shortly" just doesn't mean that in English, since the adverb "shortly" in English almost always applies to a period of time, not a physical size.  Here is a proper use of "shortly":

> Have a seat.  Your waiter will be with you shortly. [i.e., very soon]

If you are establishing a short form of a term or variable, you could say it like this:

> We will denote XXX with the short form X.

or

> For the sake of brevity, XXX will be abbreviated as X.

Comment: I would not use denote. "Let the short form X stand for XXX".

Comment: If the context is a mathematics paper, then "denote" meaning "represent symbolically" is common usage.  If the context is other than formal mathematics (or a closely-related science like physics), then I agree that denote sounds stilted and overly-formal.

Comment: The common term used in math is stand for, not denote. It sounds out of context. This is not a semiology paper about math.

Comment: @Lambie How about: "we will denote the set of all fixed points by Fix"? Does it sound right to you? Or do you only claim that denoting one symbol by another does not fit. Btw., haven't you see the use of the word "shortly" in this context? I am certain that I did. Just google "denote shortly" and find out yourselves.

Comment: @FallenApart I think you are misusing the word denote. Yes, I saw the use of shortly, it is wrong. Google does not have a mind regardless of what some may think. :)

Comment: Let x stand for or represent, NOT denote: https://www.google.com/search?ei=FhafWsv-A-bI_Qbl3IeAAQ&q=mathematical+treatise+%2B+let+x+stand+for&oq=mathematical+treatise+%2B+let+x+stand+for&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1015353.1027659.0.1028063.41.36.1.4.4.0.98.2498.35.35.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.28.1689...0j46j0i67k1j0i131i67k1j0i46k1j0i131k1j0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.0.B5bXoQERY7s

Comment: I'm not sure what you're arguing here, @Lambie.  One of the standard definitions of "denote" in [the dictionary definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/denote?s=t) is "to represent by a symbol".  And in my own experience pursuing an advanced degree in physics, this is indeed common language in academic papers using advanced mathematics. Finally, if I take your google search and swap in "denote" for "stand for", it returns almost as many hits.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Basically, I am saying what this says: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96804/is-it-correct-to-use-an-expression-we-denote-something-by-x Also, placeholders make it tough to answer the question...

Comment: That previous question talks about the the proper placement of the word "denote" within a sentence, but note that both the original question and the single answer note that use of "denote" in this sense is "very common" and "universally understood" in math papers.  So I don't think you are correct in saying that this is a misuse of the word **denote**.  You are correct that there was a misuse of **shortly**.